# The changing relationship between Democracy and Economic Growth (log GDP)

Tags: united-states, international-relations, economy, china, democracy

There has been contradicting evidence on whether being a democratic state is correlated with economic growth and/or higher GDP per capita. For instance, [Barro](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Getting_it_Right/JbWnqspSt90C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%20%20%20%20Barro%20,%20Robert%20J%20.%20Getting%20It%20Right:%20Markets%20and%20Choices%20in%20a%20Free%20Society%20.%20Cambridge,%20MA%20:%20MIT%20Press%20.%20%E2%80%94%E2%80%94%E2%80%94.%201997.%20Getting%20It%20Right:%20Markets%20and%20Choices%20in%20a%20Free%20Society.%20Cambridge,%20MA:%20MIT%20Press.%20&pg=PR9&printsec=frontcover) (1997) argues in his book that a democratic transition and providing the public with more political rights do not lead to higher economic growth per se. More recent literature by [Acemoglu](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/full/10.1086/700936) et al. (2019) challenges Barro's view and suggests that becoming a democracy is associated with higher GDP per capita in the long-run. The paper's findings are based on data 175 countries between 1960 to 2010,

I ran the same correlation between using aggregate log GDP and democracy but with 184 countries and using data from 2010 onwards until 2019.
However, I used democracy index by the EIU. I found no apparent relationship between the two indicators, and I am curious what might be causing this? For instance, one explanation might be the typical measurement error/drawbacks of relying heavily on democratic score indices such as the one used here or by Acemoglu et al. (2019).
Another hypothesis is that the world has changed drastically in the past decade, and specifically the economic rapid rise of high growth brutal autocracies such as China, UAE, Singapore, etc might be causing us to observe this small correlation between the two measures (i.e. log GDP and democracy).

[image]

Comment: Like I said when you posted previously (but deleted) I'm not surprised. The *Economist* itself said the same "Since 2002 average reported economic growth in autocracies has been twice as fast as in democracies." https://www.economist.com/graphic-detail/2022/09/29/a-study-of-lights-at-night-suggests-dictators-lie-about-economic-growth There's also a recent review that discusses under what modelling that holds and when not, but I lost the pointer to it for now (it's on another computer). Not my DV though.

Comment: There is evidence that suggests China is lying about its economic growth https://www.voanews.com/a/satellites-shed-light-on-dictators-lies-about-economic-growth/6813119.html Not to mention there have been reports of ghost cities that have been developed but little to none live there. https://www.businessinsider.com/china-empty-homes-real-estate-evergrande-housing-market-problem-2021-10

Comment: Can you make clearer what exactly you are asking? Are you interested in a critique of your research methods (such as comparing different democracy indizes) or are you interested in an explanation why autocracies might experience higher economic growth?

Comment: @Fizz thanks, I deleted my previous post because I made a coding error that made this relationship look null between the two variables. However, I have now revised my code and reposted the graph but with the correct data& code.

Comment: @xyldke Thanks, great question! I am interested in the first and I wonder if it's what's causing the latter? Specifically, I wonder if the measurement error in democracy indices is what contributes to the weaker relationship that we observe in the past decade.

Comment: I would not use the GDP but the GDP per person. If the size of the country is interesting I would rather use the population than the GDP.

Comment: To look at comparing the government and economic growth requires a lot of sifting through confounding variables. Is democratic investment into non-democratic states count towards non-democratic economic growth? A huge amount of China's growth over the last 30 years can be attributed directly towards it opening up towards western investment, yet this type of comparison attributes it entirely towards autocratic growth. A general comparison doesn't seem useful, it would likely need to be an aggregate of individual case studies on each state.

Comment: Correct David, but the same can be said about non-democratic investment flowing into democratic economic growth (e.g. Qatar and UAE spending billions of $ per year on real estate in England, building stadiums, etc), should we attribute that to England's economic growth towards its opening to autocratic investment? Perhaps yes, we should..?

The same can be said about China's capital injection into low-income yet democratic African states, should we attribute their growth to China or their democratic transition?

Comment: @Trilarion That is a good point though there are a few countries with a really small population that can skew the numbers. Based on 2017 data china is 79th in GPS per capita and that is before factoring in the cost of living. https://www.worldometers.info/gdp/gdp-per-capita/

Comment: @JoeW Then only include countries above a certain minimal size and in the fit, weigh by population again. This way China and India would have bigger influences again. It would also be possible to use plot symbols that scale in size with the population size.

Comment: How exactly are you turning "data from 2010 onwards until 2019" into a single "log  GDP" value (per country)?

Comment: When you say "aggregate log GDP", do you mean  the log of the GDP aggregate *growth* rate (for that 9 year period) as computed [here](https://datahelpdesk.worldbank.org/knowledgebase/articles/114952-how-are-aggregate-growth-rates-computed-for-nation) for instance (itself by regression)?

Answer (score 8):

Your graph is fairly meaningless, since you have plotted GDP, and not GDP per capita.

This means that the richest country appears to be "China".  China has the largest GDP, but mostly because it is so populous.  Luxembourg is far richer than China, per person, but as it's population is so small, it seems to be a poor country.

If you use GDP per capita (PPP) you get a graph like this

This shows roughly three groups: Poor countries: these have democracy scores between 1 and 7 and very low incomes.  There is little correlation for this group.  Liberal democracies countries: These have democracy values from 6 to 10 and a clear correlation, merging with the poor countries at one end. Oil rich countries: These form a scattering of points with democracy values between 2 and 9, but much richer than other countries with similar democracy values.

So a correlation exists, for countries that are no the poorest.

[image]

Comment: If it is not too much asked, could you name a few of the very poor but also very democratic countries, i.e. x axis > 6 and y axis < 10000.

Comment: Duh. I thought the OP was regressing on GDP growth, which is what most of the studies in this area are doing. That the richest countries (per capita) are democracies is so obvious that no such studies are publishable (as research).

Comment: Those are countries like Cape Verde, East Timor, Jamaica, Ghana,  India is in the same region too. @Trilarion

Comment: @JamesK agreed, the more meaningful way to look at this is GDP per capita. What year did you use for this visualization?

Comment: I think it was 2021, but it shouldn't make much difference. GDP per capita and democracy indices are not very volatile

Answer (score 5):

As James K noted, a more meaningful comparison is between Democracy Index and GDP per Capita. I just wanted to build on his answer with a little more data and a chart that also incorporates population visually (bubble size) across time. See [this visualization](https://projectseldon.org/explore?year=2020#politics), note that you can...

- View this comparison for the years 2006, 2008, 2010 - 2022,
- Export the data as a CSV or JSON,
- See and explore data sources on the left,
- And click each country to dive into more country-specific metrics.

Here's a screenshot for those metrics in 2020:

[image: 2020 GDP per Capita vs Democracy Index vs Population]

Full disclosure I am one of the founders of this project but this is exactly the type of geopolitical data we want to make easy to explore!

Comment: One of the potential issues with such charts is that the position on the democracy index is not always stable over time. If the claim is that long run GDP/person is higher in democracies, then you need to take into account for how long the country has been a democracy as well as its current state. So an even more convincing analysis would compare growth over periods where the democracy index changed significantly.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, so in a regression model with GDP per capita as as the outcome/Y variable, you would add "duration_as_democracy" as a control variable?
@matt_black

Comment: @nesta1992 Possibly. Or runs some sort of interrupted time series analysis relative looking at GDP or GDP growth before and after a significant change in democracy index.